# What is the TV show in "Transmetropolitan" about inventing drugs before they're banned by the government?

Tags: comics, vertigo-comics, transmetropolitan

The first time I read through Ellis' amazing "Transmetropolitan", I ran across a quick throwaway sequence about a fictional TV show in which the hosts invent new recreational drugs, which would then become banned by the government approximately a minute later.

I've since spent the last two hours ploughing through every issue and cannot find these panels to save my life. Nothing is mentioned in this [fairly-comprehensive list of Transmetropolitan drugs](http://politedissent.com/cbdr_b.html), either.

Does this sequence exist, and in what issue if so?

Comment: Good excuse to reread Transmet!

Comment: @MeatTrademark - Thank you! I needed one!

Comment: Ha,  yeah; know what you mean! Flipping through for the first time in years the other day, I'd totally forgotten how utterly terrific it is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a scene where that pollen that delivers news became legal for only a few minutes and some company sprayed it during that time; could that be what you were thinking of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Attaching a photo of an ad at the end of Transmet: I hate it here (2000), p-49
[image: Lonely City]

Comment: Brilliant find! Sadly the OP hasn't been active here since November 2016 so I don't know whether they'll ever see this, but if they do, I'm sure they'll be glad to know they weren't mistaken.

Comment: Ah!!! I just noticed this!!!!! Thank you so much, this is totally the answer! 

Answer (score 3):

I've been through every issue of Transmetropolitan as well as the two "specials" and I've been unable to locate any evidence of this sequence.

There are indeed a considerable number of 'throwaway' sequences involving outlandish television programmes such as the fully nude "Ebola Cola" ads, the Crom Stockley show and the decidedly non-family-friendly "Sex Puppets" but nothing that even comes close to what you've described.

[image]

Comment: For realz? What version do you have? My original read-through was with the set of trade paperbacks, no idea what edition or publishing year. I'm fully willing to admit I may have dreamed that entire set of panels up. Will leave the question open for another 2-3 days, will reward you the bounty and question if nobody else contributes anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are combining 2 different bits. 
1 is the info-pollen which is released during a gap in the law that is closed a minute later.
The other bit could be any number of drug taking moments.